# ejabberd add hook sequence

Tags: ejabberd

The ejabberd_hooks add function takes **Seq** as the final parameter. What is its function?

https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/devdoc/trunk/ejabberd_hooks.html#add-5

```
add(Hook, Host, Module, Function, Seq) -> any()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ejabberd_hooks:add(Hook, Host, Module, Function, Priority)
```

Priority is the hook rank, to determine in which order the hooks are run (when several hooks are defined for the same event). You can use it if you have dependencies between hooks.

Check the official documents [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/).